# How to write "in" query for Erlang mnesia?

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

I have a mnesia table, lets say `employee`. I need to find all employee records whose name is in `EmployeeNameList = ["Erlich", "Richard", "Gilfoyle", "Dinesh"]`. Is there a way to do this using `mnesia:select` or other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation of [Mnesia](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#select-2)
It can be done as follows:

```
get_employees_by_name(NameList) -> 
  MatchHead = #employee{name = '$1', _ = '_'},
  Result = '$_'
  MatchSpec = [ { MatchHead, [{'=:=', '$1', Name}], [Result]} || Name <- NameList ],
  F = fun() -> 
     mnesia:select(employee, MatchSpec)
  end,
  {atomic, Result} = mnesia:transaction(F),
  Result.
```